# C++ Detecting an implicit cast of 0 to a class

Tags: c++

I am calling a function in a API that returns a `Answer` object. Under some conditions, the API will return `EMPTY_answer`, which is defined as such:

```
 #define EMPTY_answer ((Answer)0)
```

of course, attempting to access a `Answer` variable or function from an `EMPTY_answer` object crashes the application.

Trying to test for it using `if(lAnswer == EMPTY_answer)` also crashes the application. Is there any way to detect if the API is returning `EMPTY_answer`?

#### Edit:

I didn't code the api and I can't modify it in any way, I'm just digging through .h files trying to figure this out. And yes, I am aware that casting 0 to a class is a bit *too* creative to put it mildly. I just noticed that the `==` operator is overridden

```
(...)
class ExportedByJS0CORBA Answer
{
   (...)
   int __stdcall operator==(Answer *ipt) const;
}
```

the function being called is

```
static SubClassOfAction Query();
```

I'm simplifying names and quite a few layers of inheritance
To be more precise, it crashes with a Segmentation Fault.

Comment: Show us the declaration for `Answer`

Comment: Could you also post the declaration of the function that is returning this? Is it returning a reference or an object?

Comment: Probably the `Answer` class should be fixed, so that objects constructed by `Answer(0)` don't crash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Answer` is a class type, as the text of your questions suggest, then `(Answer) 0` will construct a temporary `Answer` object using the constructor that accepts `0` as an argument (apparently such constructor exists). In this case attempting to access the members of that object will not crash anything, unless `Answer` class is specifically implemented to crash in this case (intentionally or unintentionally). So your "Of course..." claim makes no sense whatsoever. There's no immediate reason for such code to crash.

If you observe crashed in `someAnswer == EMPTY_answer` comparison, that would either mean that the implementation of `==` operator is buggy, or that either the LHS or the RHS are not valid objects. For example, it might turn out that it is illegal (by design) to construct an `Answer` object by conversion from `0`. If so, then you should simply stop using `(Answer) 0` in your code and find another, correctly supported object value to indicate an empty answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot modify the code declaring and using (Answer) 0. But if there is no reason for it to crash, the problem then lies somewhere else than the (Answer) 0

Answer (score 4):

Instead of doing a very ugly cast which is almost guaranteed to trigger undefined behavior, just make a static global variable which is used as the "empty" answer. You don't need to use this object in any way, just make it exist so it can be used as a sentinel.

In Answer.h:

```
extern const Answer EMPTY_answer;
```

In Answer.cpp:

```
const Answer EMPTY_answer;  // use any constructor parameters that will be appropriate
```

Comment: To avoid accidents, `EMPTY_answer` should be declared `const`.

Comment: There is no undefined behavior, it simply calls `Answer(0)` to convert the `0` to an `Answer`. If there isn't such a constructor in `Answer`, it doesn't compile.

Comment: @sth, I always thought a C-style cast could coerce anything into anything else whether the conversion was well-defined or not. Maybe I'm just thinking of pointer casts.

Answer (score 0):

your original method of just checking for `EMPTY_answer` is the right way to solve this. Your real problem is why that crashes. What type is `lAnswer`? Or `Answer` for that matter... you can't cast `0` to a class like that.

Comment: Answer must have a convert constructor which takes an integral value